# CiviCRM Views Showing Wrong Custom Data

Tags: civicase, activities, drupal-views

I have a strange Views problem. I'm on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.4.0. I produced a View of case activities by showing several custom fields, one custom field called "placement". The placement field has options: None, A, B, C.

On the most recent case activities called Update, the placement field is B. However, when I look at Views, the placement field is C. The Views has current revision set to TRUE, deleted case FALSE, deleted activities FALSE, and deleted contacts FALSE.

If I go to cases and change the custom placement field to A, then Views show B. Basically, the case and Views are not matching. In fact, the Views page shows the option after what is selected in cases. Is this a recent bug?

Comment: You're a few releases behind so would be worth upgrading and seeing whether you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading resolved the issues!